# Relation between Fourier coefficients of two (weakly holomorphic) modular forms

Tags: modular-forms

Assume that $\Gamma \leq \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ be a certain discrete subgroup (for example, congruence subgroups) and let $\Gamma' = \alpha\Gamma\alpha^{-1}$ for some $\alpha\in \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$. If $f:\mathfrak{H}\to \mathbb{C}$ is a (weakly) holomorphic modular form on $\Gamma$ of weight $k\in \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{Z}$, then $g:\mathfrak{H}\to \mathbb{C}$ defined as $g(\tau) = f(\alpha^{-1}\tau)$ is a (weakly) holomorphic modular form on $\Gamma'$ of the same weight. If all $\Gamma, \Gamma', \alpha$ are given and the Fourier expansion of $g$ is given as $g(\tau) = \sum_{n\geq -N} a_{n}q^{n}$, can we compute the Fourier expansion of $f(\tau)$ from this?

Here I give more concrete situation: let $$\Gamma = \Gamma_{\theta} = \langle \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\0&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\rangle = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\equiv \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \text{ or }\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\,(\mathrm{mod }2)\right\} $$
and $\gamma = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&-1\end{pmatrix}$, so that 
$$
\gamma\Gamma_{\theta}\gamma^{-1} =\Gamma_{0}(2). 
$$
Now the theta function $\theta(\tau) = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}e^{\pi i n^{2}\tau}$ is weight $1/2$ holomorphic modular form on $\Gamma_{\theta}$, and then 
$$
g(\tau) = \theta\left( -\frac{\tau + 1}{\tau}\right)
$$
is a modular form on $\Gamma_{0}(2)$ of weight $1/2$. Can we compute the Fourier coefficients of $g$? Conversely, if we have a modular form  $g(\tau)$ on $\Gamma_{0}(2)$ which the Fourier coefficients are known, can we compute the Fourier expansion of corresponding function 
$$
f(\tau) = g\left( - \frac{1}{\tau+1}\right)?
$$

Comment: $\theta(-\frac{1}{z+1}) =(-i(z+1))^{-1/2} \theta(z+1)= (-i(z+1))^{-1/2} \sum_n (-1)^n e^{i \pi n^2 z}$ $=(-i(z+1))^{-1/2} (\theta(z)-2 \theta(2z)) $. In general for $h \in M_k(\Gamma_0(N))$ to find $h(\frac{-1}{Nz+1})$ you'll want to express $h(z-\frac{1}{N})$ as a sum of newforms of different level (from the commuting relations of the Hecke operators [with the Fricke involution](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/courses/11-12/nt/notes/lecture13.pdf) )

Comment: @reuns How can I deal with the term $(-i(z+1))^{-1/2}$? How it affects the Fourier expansion?

Comment: Oops I meant $\theta(-\frac{1}{z+1}) =(-i(z+1))^{1/2} \theta(z+1)= (-i(z+1))^{1/2} \sum_n (-1)^n e^{i \pi n^2 z}$. You don't want to deal or remove the $.^{1/2}$ term, it is there : $(cz+d)^{-1/2} \theta(\frac{az+b}{cz+d})$ is periodic. This is what is denoted $ f|_k \gamma(z)$ in most texts, with $k=1/2,\gamma(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}, f = \theta$